# Multiple Count() in Database

Tags: mysql

I'm making a survey-applican with winforms and VB. This is the SQL I got so far to show statistics:

```
SELECT
    tblAlt.altText,
    Count(tblAnswers.answerID)
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

This returns each alternatives for a question, and how many answered them. Is there a way I can count how many answered in total with the same SQL-query?

Tables involved are:

```
_______________     _______________     ___________  _______________
|_tblUsers____|     |_tblAnswers___|    |_tblAlt__|  |_tblQuestion_|
| userID      |     | answerAltID  |    | altID   |  | questID     |
| username    |     | userID       |    | altText |  | questText   |
|_____________|     |______________|    |_questID_|  |_____________|
```

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I used in the end:

```
SELECT
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID),
(SELECT COUNT(answerID) FROM tblAnswers, tblAlt 
WHERE tblAnswers.answerAltID = tblAlt.altID 
AND tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & ") as total_count
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an subquery to do this, something like:

```
SELECT
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID),
(SELECT COUNT(answerID) FROM tblAnswers) as total_count
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Some Resources:

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-subquery.html

Answer (score 2):

Use ROLLUP:

```
SELECT
    tblAlt.altText,
    Count(tblAnswers.answerID)
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText WITH ROLLUP;
```

---

If you want one-time computation(to make query efficient), use CROSS JOIN. Don't worry, this CROSS JOIN won't yield cartesian product, it's only one row. This might be faster than subquery approach:

```
SELECT
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID), x.total_count    
FROM tblAlt
cross join (SELECT COUNT(answerID) as total_count FROM tblAnswers) as x 

LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Or use MySqlism, might be faster:

```
SELECT
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID), @total_count as total_count
FROM tblAlt
cross join (SELECT @total_count := COUNT(answerID) FROM tblAnswers) as x

LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Or you can use multi-statements. Note, `SET` statements doesn't appear on ADO.NET's DataReader or DataTable. ADO.NET can still get the results from your actual query. This has a certainty to be faster among all approaches:

```
SET @total_count := (SELECT COUNT(answerID) FROM tblAnswers);
SELECT
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID), @total_count as total_count
FROM tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questionID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

Comment: What a beautiful answer! I've learned something today. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html